# Inline Razor conditional statement that will only display html attribute and value if condition is met

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, razor, asp.net-core-mvc

Is there anyway I can change this inline razor conditional statement so that the class attribute isn't always output to the html unless the class is actually being added. I don't want my html to have class="" in it.

```
<div id="wrapper" class="@(isMobile ? "mobileView" : "")">
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about

```
<div id="wrapper" @(isMobile ? "class=\"mobileView\"" : "")>
```

Comment: It doesn't work : it shows error "Missing attribute name"